# Angular routing make child path full page takeover

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am creating an angular app which has an order history which will show all previous orders. On selecting one, it will open a new page and show you the details of that specific order. Since the 2 will be linked, I have creating the order item as a child of the order history component, like so.

```
{
    path: 'history', component: OrderHistoryComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':orderNo',
        component: OrderItemComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
```

But it comes up like so:

[image]

And the path is `localhost:4200/#/history/order1`

as you can see, the order item component comes below the order history component. Is there a way to have it as a child route but still have it take over the full page?
I think this will be the best way to ass the information as I will be getting the order history json and will be using the specific order number to display information about that order.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could add the landing page of your orders as a child to the 'history' route and make the history route itself a componentless route like this:

```
{
    path: 'history',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: OrderHistoryComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':orderNo',
        component: OrderItemComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
```

Then the path `localhost:4200/#/history` will show the `OrderHistoryComponent` and `localhost:4200/#/history/order1` will show the `OrderItemComonent`.

Comment: That seems like a good workaround. 
Would the data of the json be passed on to `OrderItemComponent` from `OrderHistoryComponent` ? 

I have tried passing data to components before (not linked) and it was always tricky, especially when refreshing, to hold the data. Ideally I wouldn't want to do a get request every time someone refreshes, if they are on the :orderNo page

Comment: No data will be passed from `OrderHistoryComponent` to `OrderItemComponent`. I my proposal these two components would be siblings, so either `OrderHistoryComponent` or `OrderItemComponent` is active.

Answer (score 0):

There is slight change in the **OrderHistoryComponent** you have to place router outlet so whenever children routes of OrderHistoryComponent accessed then they will be rendered in router-outlet present in OrderHistoryComponent.

Routing is Good

```
       {
    path: 'history', component: OrderHistoryComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':orderNo',
        component: OrderItemComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
```

In the **OrderHistoryComponent** template the changes have to be made like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then try using *ngIf Directive which checks router url and it have to show history div only if route path matches url/history then you problem will be solved.
**OrderHistory Component.ts**

```
 constructor(public router: Router){
       console.log(router.url);
  }
```

**OrderHistory Component.html**
Other than router outlet what ever the code you have written bind it with *ngIf Directive.

```
<div
  *ngIf="router.url == '/history'"
>
Your order table will be here i think
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that is how I currently have it, so I do have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on the `order-history.component.html` file, but the problem is that `order-item.component.html` is shown underneath order history, when I want it to be a fully page takeover